# Highchart: Bar Chart with time duration

Tags: time, highcharts, bar-chart, duration

I want to create a bar chart with time duration on the bottom axis. It' working for decimal numbers, like 300.5 seconds, or 50.3 hours, but i would like to have the following format:
Hours:Minutes:Seconds. I tried some thing with datalabelformat: datetime, but with no success.

The data would be for example: 
Member1 - 10:05:18
Member2 - 12:52:20
Member3 - 18:10:30
Member4 - 19:20:10
Member5 - 19:30:45

Anybody got an idea how to realize that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does your data look like?  Are the x values in a time format (epoch milliseconds)?

Comment: @Mark: the raw data are seconds. but i could convert it to whatever I want using php, I guess

Comment: Are these values the number of seconds since what?  Epoch?  Some arbitrary value?  Do you want the axis to show the difference between these values in Hour:Min:Sec?

Answer (score 3):

You need to set min value and tickInterval, then set dateTimeLabels.

```
dateTimeLabelFormats: {
            millisecond: '%H:%M:%S',
            second: '%H:%M:%S',
            minute: '%H:%M:%S',
            hour: '%H:%M:%S',
            day: '%H:%M:%S',
            week: '%H:%M:%S',
            month: '%H:%M:%S',
            year: '%H:%M:%S'
        }
```

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/TynTT/1/

Answer (score 3):

I came here searching for a solution to my problem. Not sure if this is exactly what you want, and I cannot put in a comment due to low reputation. But this is how I was able to solve it.

This provides result in hh:mm. You can modify it to include seconds.
http://jsfiddle.net/TynTT/11/

It has the y axis in hh:mm format and also displays datalabels as hh:mm.

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    yAxis: {
        type: 'time',
        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                var time = this.value;
                var hours1=parseInt(time/3600000);
                var mins1=parseInt((parseInt(time%3600000))/60000);
                return (hours1 < 10 ? '0' + hours1 : hours1) + ':' + (mins1 < 10 ? '0' + mins1 : mins1);
            }   
        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: [1000000, 26500000, 17000050, 79000000, 56000000, 124000000],
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            formatter: function () {
                var time = this.y / 1000;
                var hours1=parseInt(time/3600);
                var mins1=parseInt((parseInt(time%3600))/60);
                return (hours1 < 10 ? '0' + hours1 : hours1) + ':' + (mins1 < 10 ? '0' + mins1 : mins1);
            }
        },
    }]
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I improved above configs by reusing the HC methods:

```
    durationbar: {
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        yAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            showFirstLabel: false,
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                millisecond: '%H:%M:%S'
            },
            units: [[
                'millisecond',
                [1000]
            ], [
                'second',
                [1, 2, 5, 10, 15, 30]
            ], [
                'minute',
                [1, 2, 5, 10, 15, 30]
            ], [
                'hour',
                [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12]
            ], [
                'day',
                [1]
            ], [
                'week',
                [1]
            ], [
                'month',
                [1, 3, 6]
            ], [
                'year',
                null
            ]],
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: null,
            pointFormat: '{point.name}: <b>{point.dataLabel.text.textStr}</b><br/>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    formatter() {
                        return this.series.chart.time.dateFormat('%H:%M:%S', this.y)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

[image: screenshot]